# eclipse did not display the name of file from a project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have tried changing font and color and it does not work please help. [random symbol on file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acSwQ.png)

Comment: Look like your PC's fonts issue.

Comment: ok I will try to change my PC font